# Does not found Listblob() in CloudBlobContainer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my app i want all the blob of my container but in my code (as below) there is not Listblob() method in CloudBlobContainer variable container. Am i missing something?

```
var credentials = new StorageCredentials("xxx", "a37bijfRGGdgaVU+ITEIi0Cp1VrbzMM7Bc9PbMOw2FPAz9twgR+lbTzqGhBfHeJe7UfEp4CXtLxqY5Ek0/5zdg==");
        var client = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/"), credentials);
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("publicimage");

//this container variable has not ListBlobs() method
        foreach(IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync())
        {

        }
```

Comment: Which version of storage client library are you using?

Comment: @GauravMantri I believe it should not matter, since ListBlob is available since 1.7 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee772878(v=azure.95).aspx

Comment: I guess your package references are not correct. @Zanak can you confirm that you used nuget to add package references?

Comment: @Abhijeet I think it would as there have been some changes in the functions between 1.7 and 2.0. Also if I understand correctly, functions are different between full .Net storage client library and .Net storage client library for Windows 8/Windows Phone apps.

Comment: @Abhijeet ya i install windows azure storage package from Nuget.

Comment: @GauravMantri is right, ListBlobs would be missing if the platform does not support synchronous methods.

Comment: @SerdarOzler-Microsoft so wp8.1 doesn't support that? An other idea to do?

Comment: @Zanak, yes, you will not find ListBlobs in the Windows Phone library. I just added an answer to give you more details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ListBlobs is a synchronous method and therefore is missing on platforms that do not support synchronous methods such as Windows Phone. The reason is that calling a synchronous method on a UI thread would block the UI and make the application unresponsive.

The alternative is to use the *Async overloads. However, please note that there is no ListBlobsAsync, because there is no async counterpart of IEnumerable in .NET. So, you should call [ListBlobsSegmentedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) and handle the continuation token that it returns.

If you would like to see an example usage, I would recommend looking at Azure Storage Client Library's unit tests (see test CloudBlobContainerListBlobsSegmentedAsync in [CloudBlobContainerTest.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/3187d0f14d78fbb060dcbc9e7be6aee8a36b3532/Test/WindowsRuntime/Blob/CloudBlobDirectoryTest.cs#L123)).

Comment: Link to the usage example is broken

Comment: Replacing the broken link in the answer: [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/3187d0f14d78fbb060dcbc9e7be6aee8a36b3532/Test/WindowsRuntime/Blob/CloudBlobDirectoryTest.cs#L123) is a link to an example in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two Nuget packages and you will be able to find Listblobs

```html
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
```